# Assigning property's of HTML Element Objects returned by getElementById() in a statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop

Here is a statement that makes sense to me

```
var x = object.function();
```

variable x's value is equal to object's function's return value.

or

```
var y = object.property;
```

variable y's value is equal to object's property.

**But I don't understand the following code:**

```
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
```

In the above, the object `document` is calling ITS method `getElementById()`. Which returns an HTML Object `demo` which is calling ITS object property `innerHTML`? Is this correct?

**Here's an even confusing statement...**

```
<button onclick="getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()">What is the time?</button>
```

In the code above, does the innerHTML property belong to the HTML Object Element demo? If so, then which object does the getElementById() method belong to?

Being new to OOP and Javascript I'm can't wrap by head around the concept of `object.function.property;` statements. or `function.property;` statements.

Comment: [Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: Does this make sense to you? `var y = object.property; object.property2 = y;` ?

Comment: If yes, then consider `document.getElementById('demo')` to be your `object` and `innerHTML` to be your `property2`. :)

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` method belongs to `document` object here.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript each function/code block is executed in scope or context if you like. This scope is referenced by the keyword `this`. So when you try to access some variable, or call some function, it should be declared in that scope, otherwise it is looked for in the global scope, which is the `window` object. When you assign the `onclick` handler like you specified, the scope for the javascript block `getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()` will be the button itself, which belongs to the document, which has the function `getElementById` specified. So you are calling the function `getElementById` specified by the `document` object, like in your previous example, and than you are assigning it's `innerHTML` property to the string value of the newly created object `new Date()`.

However, the right implementation should look like this (assuming you are using jQuery)

```
// Call the function after the DOM is ready
$(function() {
   // Find the button on the page
   $("button")
       .click(function() {     // Assign the handle for the click event
          // Finds the div on the page and assign its innerHTML
          $("#demo")[0].innerHTML = new Date();
       });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**document.getElementById("demo")** is an DOM object refers to Dom element and **innerHTML** is a property of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this

`var x = object.function();`

Which, in your question is equivalent to

`var DOMObject = document.getElementById("demo"); // ----------- (1)`

Now, This

`var y = object.property;`

in your question is equivalent to

`var InnerHtml = DOMObject.innerHTML; // ----------- (From 1)`

So, at the end of the day,

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";`

is just a short hand way of doing

```
var DOMObject = document.getElementById("demo");
DOMObject.innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
```